# Training GAN using Galaxy Zoo dataset, TensorFlow, and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

What is the proper way to import [Galaxy Zoo dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/galaxy-zoo-the-galaxy-challenge/data) in order to train a simple GAN using TensorFlow and Keras? Is there the same easy way as with importing MNIST, for instance?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a simple import for it since it is not keras [dataset](https://keras.io/api/datasets/).

You will have to download the data and preprocess it yourself before feeding into the network. If you go to the kaggle link and go to notebooks, you can see how other people have preprocessed their data for training

It matter what you want to train on and what you are classifying. If you want to train on images to classify all or some of the classes in the csv, you will need your data as images and classifications as labels. If you wanted to use some classification to predict another classification, some classes would be the data and others would be the label you are predicting.

I recommend importing the training csv into a pandas [dataframe](https://www.kaggle.com/helmehelmuto/keras-cnn)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('../input/44352/training_solutions_rev1.csv')
```

You would then have to create a custom generator for your images since they are not organized by class in the folder structure.

Comment: Thank you! The situation has cleared up. As for the data preprocessing, I assumed so too, just needed to clarify this. I want to train my GAN to generate fabricated galaxy images. The model and script work perfectly with MNIST and CIFAR-10, and I'm currently trying to configure it for the Galaxy Zoo.

Comment: You may have to resize the images to your input, galaxyZoo is 424x424 and also normalize slightly differently than CIFAR and MNIST